# Installing codecs for mov to mp4 conversion ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, codec, mov

I have been trying to convert a .mov file to a .mp4 file for a while now i think this is the correct code to do it.

```
ffmpeg  -i P1010989.MOV -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
```

But here is my output

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'P1010989.MOV':
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11584 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 640x480, 11315 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 256 kb/s
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[mp4 @ 0x95b0080]track 1: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 11315 kb/s, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)
```

So i am trying to install the correct codecs and im a bit lost and do with some help.

Do i need to install the codecs separately and where do i download and install them from?

Code really do with some help thanks.

Comment: Hi LordNeckBeard thanks for the reply i was going for mp4 for the  mobile platform and compression, perhaps im wrong looking to take multi video formats and output all to the same so i was thinking mp4 as a good solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be, 16000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 256 kb/s
[mp4 @ 0x95b0080]track 1: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container
```

This is telling you not that the codec is missing, but that it is not compatible with the MP4 format.

You can fix this issue by using a different audio codec.

```
ffmpeg -i P1010989.MOV -vcodec copy -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k out.mp4
```